# append() doesnt work EmbeddedDocumentListField (mongoengine)

Tags: python-3.x, database, mongodb, mongoengine

I worked with python a lot but I'm new to mongoengine.I saw in a tutorial someone using the append() method to add an item to a EmbeddedDocumentListField.
unfortunately, I didn't manage to add a new item to a EmbeddedDocumentListField, and the append() method didn't work (even not with ListField) - i get an ''EmbeddedDocumentListField' object has no attribute 'append'' error

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here for us to help. Please provide additional details and perhaps a [reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: i get a 'EmbeddedDocumentListField' object has no attribute 'append' error. Im looking for a way to do this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.